# Mongodb, use selected document value to update field in same document using single operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Lets say you are making a simply todo app and you have a structure that looks like this:

```
{
[userId]: {
  nextTaskId:3,
  tasks: {
    1: "take out the trash",
    2: "pick up milk"
  }
}
```

When adding a task, I'd like to create a new record using the the nextTaskId and also increment it.  I have seen other examples using a aggregation function like $concat or the like, but that doesn't fit my usecase.

I'd like to be able to reference the field in my update, something like:

`db.tasks.updateOne({_id:5}, {$inc:{nextId:1}, $set: {"tasks.$nextId":{"new task" }}})`

the field does get incremented, however the tasks key is not 3, but $nextId and I also tried using it as a value, as in:

`db.tasks.updateOne({_id:5}, {$inc:{nextId:1}, $set: {"tasks.3":{"$nextId" }}})`

that doesn't work either.  of course, I could do this by making 2 individual operations, one to get the next id and increment it, and another to create the new task record, but i'm hoping to do it with a single operation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would be helpful if you can give a concrete JSON sample. From your example, it seems like you are using dynamic values as field names, which is generally considered as an anti-pattern and it is suggested to restructure your schema if possible.

Comment: Thanks for reading the question and for your feedback.  

Regarding the concrete JSON example.  I have it there above, I didn't put in a BSON record id, instead notated it as [userId].  

Later, I have the example queries, which are normal mongosh syntax.

To be more clear, basically I'm trying to reference current record values in my update without having to do two separate operations.  This is for concurrency issues, along with performance concerns.


I've seen this done using the aggregation fcns for example with $concate (ie a full name field being the join of first and last).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use update with aggregation pipeline to achieve the behaviour in one single update statement. Use `$objectToArray` and `$arrayToObject` to manipulate the `tasks` array.

```js
db.collection.update({
  _id: 5
},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "tasks": {
        "$objectToArray": "$tasks"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "nextTaskId": {
        $add: [
          "$nextTaskId",
          1
        ]
      },
      tasks: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$tasks",
          [
            {
              k: {
                $toString: "$nextTaskId"
              },
              // your input for the new task
              v: "next task"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "tasks": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$tasks"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KYf_RMrqDCf) for your reference.

Comment: Wow, Ok Mr Mongodb Wizard.
I didn't realize there was that $addFields ability.  
looking at your code, it looks like:
1) the first $addFields converts the tasks obj to an array
2) the second increments the nextTaskId and adds a new array element
3) convert the tasks array back to an object.

I'm guessing it's not easy to simply add a property (task obj) to the tasks obj, hence the use of the array.

Nice to see how you can reference the current record values so easy with the $[label] syntax.

And, thank you for going the extra step of creating that playground workspace!

Comment: Ray, is there a way to simply add a property to the "tasks" object without having to convert it to an array, doing a concat, then back to object?

Comment: I'm guessing the complexity is due to as you mentioned earlier, the dynamic key.  
You get around that with that k,v construct to explicitly create the hash that you're adding...  I guess you can't on the fly do it otherwise

Comment: @paultman yes you are right. I still advise that you change your schema if possible. For example, if you have a plain array of strings, you can simply `$push` new task inside. Also, from the current context we received here, I don't see the necessity for maintaining the taskId. You may want to reconsider your schema or supplement more context for us to have a look.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/_e6saZMWwYI

there I hard coded the key, i wish I could have used, "$nextTaskId"

Comment: @@ray I need the task id to keep track of UI updates and reference the user tasks.  
Probably more trouble trying to make this a single db operation/update rather than two operations, first incrementing the task id, and the second using that task id to add a new task to the tasks prop.

Comment: @paultman I guess $mergeObjects does not support dynamic field, at least for now. And I think it could be rather too much for this question as of now. I suggest that you can open a new question for that if you want to continue the discussion and leave this question as focused as of now.